# spawning jenkins slave on openshift without jenkins master

Tags: git, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

After reading around I understood that I have to have a Jenkins master present to be able to spawn a Jenkins slave on OpenShift via Git web hook. But is there a way to spawn Jenkins slave without an existing Jenkins master?

Thanks a lot to All!

Answer (score 0):

According discussion with dev, its not good ide, as it could slow and ugly. The recomanded solution is to have always Jenkins Master running with spawned slaves on the fly.